# Dificuldade em obter objeto dentro de uma CDI Extension

Tags: java, cdi, extension

Estou querendo criar um extension no meu projeto para que ele passe a interpretar uma anotação propria, para isso eu tenha inicialmente um @Producer do objeto Scheduler do Quartz, vejam

```
public class SchedulerProducer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SchedulerProducer.class.getName());

    private static final String SCHEDULER_CONFIGURATION_FILE = "scheduler.properties";

    private StdSchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory;

    @Produces
    public Scheduler createScheduler(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Criando instância do Scheduler");

        try {

            if (stdSchedulerFactory == null) {
                createStdSchedulerFactory();
            }

            return stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Falha ao criar o Scheduler", e);
           return null;
        }
    }

    private void createStdSchedulerFactory() throws SchedulerException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putAll(getDefaultProperties());
       properties.putAll(FileUtils.loadPropertiesFile(SCHEDULER_CONFIGURATION_FILE));

        this.stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    }

    private Properties getDefaultProperties() {

        Properties defaultProp = new Properties();
        defaultProp.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "AUTO");
        defaultProp.put("org.quartz.jobStore.class", "org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore");
        defaultProp.put("org.quartz.threadPool.class", "org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool");
        defaultProp.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "10");
        defaultProp.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority", "5");
        defaultProp.put("org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class", CdiAwareJobFactory.class.getName());
        return defaultProp;
    }

}
```

Até ai tudo certo minha dúvida é como injetar dentro do extension o Scheduler produzido pela classe acima ?

Abaixo minha Extension:

```
public class SchedulerExtension implements Extension {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SchedulerExtension.class.getName());

    private Set<Class> foundManagedJobClasses = new HashSet<Class>();

    public <X> void findScheduledJobs(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<X> pat, BeanManager beanManager) {

        Class<X> beanClass = pat.getAnnotatedType().getJavaClass();

        if (!org.quartz.Job.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass)) {
            return;
        }

        SchedulerJob schedulerJob = pat.getAnnotatedType().getAnnotation(SchedulerJob.class);
        if (schedulerJob != null) {
            foundManagedJobClasses.add(beanClass);
        }
    }

    public <X> void scheduleJobs(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery afterBeanDiscovery, BeanManager beanManager) {

        List<String> foundJobNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Class jobClass : this.foundManagedJobClasses) {

            if (foundJobNames.contains(jobClass.getSimpleName())) {
                continue;
            }

            foundJobNames.add(jobClass.getSimpleName());

            // preciso do scheduler aqui para fazero agendamento da tarefa, alguma ideia ?
        }

    }

}
```

Alguem saberia como eu poderia pegar a instancia do scheduler sendo que não é possivel injeta-la nesse momento ainda ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html), as extensões executam antes de qualquer bean ser criado, justamente com o propósito de se poder interferir em como eles são criados.

Contudo, você pode escutar a [eventos](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#_container_lifecycle_events) e, após a inicialização, acessar os beans através do [`BeanManager`](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#_the_literal_beanmanager_literal_object).

Portanto, eu diria que o processo poderia, em teoria, funcionar da seguinte forma:

1. Escutar o último evento: `AfterDeploymentValidation`
2. Recuperar o bean usando `BeanManager`. [Exemplo](https://gist.github.com/joelbinn/5023363):

   ```
   BeanManager bm = ...;
   Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) bm.getBeans(clazz).iterator().next();
   CreationalContext<T> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
   T object = (T) bm.getReference(bean, clazz, ctx);
   ```

Alternativamente, você pode salvar a lista de jobs encontrados num atributo e processar a lista posteriormente em outro bean. Para recuperar a lista, basta [injetar](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#_creating_an_literal_extension_literal) a extensão no bean. Exemplo:

```
@Inject    
MyBean(SchedulerExtension ext, Scheduler scheduler) {
    for (Class jobClass : this.foundManagedJobClasses) {    
        //scheduler...
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo, observando o evento AfterDeploymentValidation consegui pegar a instância do meu objeto e fazer o que eu precisava, show de bola.